# Tkinter Canvas items stored cleared and recalled

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am a beginner messing around in python 3.6 with tkinter canvas and have built a function that generates a solar system at random using elipses and the random method.

I would like to be able to save these items and all their attributes like their tags and bindings so that I can clear the canvas and draw a new random system. I would then like to go back to the first generated system if I need to.

I do not want to save the canvas as an image as I am binding the items to functions. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I sounds a bit like you store information in the GUI. I would store it in objects from which the GUI representation can be (re)built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you only get the items "id" as a handle to that item, and while you can delete an item with a given ID, you can not recreate it just with that ID.

What you *could* do is to given all those elements a common tag and use `tag_lower` and `tag_raise` to hide and show the items below and above the "background" pane. The objects are still on the canvas, but can not be seen and do not react to e.g. mouse events.

```
import tkinter, random
root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

space = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200, fill="#000000")
for _ in range(10):
    x, y = random.randint(0, 200), random.randint(0, 200)
    s = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill="#ffff00", tags="star")
    canvas.tag_bind(s, "<Button>", lambda e: print("twinkle"))

root.after(3000, lambda: canvas.tag_lower("star", space))
root.after(6000, lambda: canvas.tag_raise("star", space))
root.mainloop()
```

---

Update: As suggested by OP [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788787/python-tkinter-canvas-items-stored-cleared-and-recalled/48789366#comment84651091_48789366), one can also set the items' state to `hidden`, being probably the clearer option and not needing some obscure (-ing) background item.

```
root.after(3000, lambda: canvas.itemconfig("star", state="hidden"))
root.after(6000, lambda: canvas.itemconfig("star", state="normal"))
```

Comment: This could have been a problem because I already tag all the items based on the kind of body they are in space ie. 'star', 'barren', 'asteroid', 'gas' etc.  

But items can have multiple tags. So I will just generate a new tag each time I generate a system therefor each item will have two tags ie. 'gas', 'system01'. I can then use tag_lower and tag_raise to achieve the effect of changing systems. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: That ”use” of `or` is horrible. If you need functions with more than just an expression, use proper functions, not lambda and hacks with `or`.

Comment: @BlackJack That use of `or` does not have anything to do with the answer and is just to add some output without blowing that snippet up to 20 lines. But if you _really_ think this justifies a downvote, well, whatever, I can remove them...

Comment: I actually found out that I can instead set the state of the items with the 'system1' tag to 'hidden' which achieves the same effect but doesn't require me to keep a rectangle as a screen for the items.  ie:
canvas.itemconfig('system1', state='hidden')

Comment: @JoeyScott Ah, right, I did not think of that. That's much better. You might want to add this as an answer of your own, or I can add it to my answer, whichever you prefer.